# Написать функцию, которая заменяет в полученной строке большие буквы на маленькие, маленькие – на большие, а цифры – на знак нижнего подчеркивания

Tags: javascript, строки

Написать функцию, которая заменяет в полученной строке
**большие** буквы на маленькие, маленькие – на **большие**, а
цифры – на знак нижнего подчеркивания. не могу разобраться, как заменить цифры на знак нижнего подчеркивания

```
const str = 'БОЛЬШИЕ БУКВЫ на маленькие, маленькие – НА БОЛЬШИЕ 123456789';

function changeRegister (str) {
let upperWord = 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ';
let lowerWord = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя';
let number = '1234567890';
let result = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(upperWord.includes(str[i])) {
      result.push(str[i].toLowerCase());
    }
    else if(lowerWord.includes(str[i])) {
      result.push(str[i].toUpperCase());
    }
    else if(number.includes(str[i])) {
      result.push(str[i].replace('_'));
    }
    else {
      result.push(str[i]);
    }
  }
  return result.join('');
};

console.log(str);
console.log(changeRegister(str));
```

Comment: Вместо `result.push(str[i].replace('_'))` написать просто `result.push('_'))` .... А вообще зачем тут массив и пуш в коде - не ясно... Если надо менять символы в строке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const str = 'БОЛЬШИЕ БУКВЫ на маленькие, маленькие – НА БОЛЬШИЕ 123456789';

function changeRegister (str) {
let result = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(/^\d+$/.test(str[i])) {
      result.push('_');
    }
    else if(str[i].toUpperCase() === str[i]) {
      result.push(str[i].toLowerCase());
    }
    else if(str[i].toLowerCase() === str[i]) {
      result.push(str[i].toUpperCase());
    }
    else {
      result.push(str[i]);
    }
  }
  return result.join('');
};

console.log(str);
console.log(changeRegister(str));
```

```
БОЛЬШИЕ БУКВЫ на маленькие, маленькие – НА БОЛЬШИЕ 123456789
большие буквы НА МАЛЕНЬКИЕ, МАЛЕНЬКИЕ – на большие _________
```